# Android Studio 6.0 merger fail

Tags: android, android-studio

Just updated to the latest version of Android Studio and i get this error in the AndroidManifest file

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/project_launcher_icon) from AndroidManifest.xml:48:9
>       is also present at com.github.anupcowkur:reservoir:1.1.1:6:45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher)
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:44:5 to override

I tried adding tools:replace="@drawable/ic_drawer" in my manifest  but i get this error:

```
Error:(44, 5) tools:replace specified at line:44 for attribute tools:drawable/ic_drawer, but no new value specified
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to know what are the changes expected in our manifest files in order to make them compatible with the new merger.

Comment: Have you considered changing the accepted answer for this @connector ?

Comment: please tell me one thing tools:replace should i add this inside application tag of my project manifest or inside application tag of my library please tell me it will be really helpful for me ??

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Following Android Studio's suggestion and adding the following attribute `tools:replace="icon"` should allow it to build your app successfully, without resorting to using the old manifest merger (which isn't a very forward-looking solution indeed).

Of course, you'll first have to declare the namespace "tools" in order to use it:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              package="com.sample.app" >
```

Comment: There are a number of things you might run into with the new manifest merger. 

All the new changes are documented here:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Comment: please tell me one thing tools:replace should i add this inside application tag of my project manifest or inside application tag of my library please tell me it will be really helpful for me ??

Answer (score 9):

You should add `tools:replace="icon"`, just like the error message says.

Additional attributes can be replaced using the syntax `tools:replace="icon,name,theme"`

Comment: please tell me one thing tools:replace should i add this inside application tag of my project manifest or inside application tag of my library please tell me it will be really helpful for me ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur add it to the application tag of your project

Comment: After some researches I found that it should be replaced with tools:replace="icon, label, theme" or other combination, containing all presenting in Manifest attributes.

Answer (score 9):

look here:
[All markers belong to the Android tools namespace, therefore you must declare the namespace in any AndroidManifest.xml containing at least one marker :
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.tests.flavorlib.app"
**xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"**>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
   **tools:replace=”icon, label”**/>
</manifest>
```

you should add xlms:tools and tools:replace those two lines in manifest file.

Comment: Points for actually showing where to add the item, just as well you could have implicitly stated where to add it. Good job

Comment: please tell me one thing tools:replace should i add this inside application tag of my project manifest or inside application tag of my library please tell me it will be really helpful for me ??

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio 0.6 use the new manifest merger tool. This new merger was introduced in version 0.10 of the plugin. As of 0.11, this tool is used by default by the gradle plugin.

In order to revert to the old manifest merger, please add to your build.gradle the following configuration :

`android {
  useOldManifestMerger true
}`

Comment: I would say that this is not the solution, but a temporal patch. In fact they will remove the support for the old manifest merger on Android Studio 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked. Try adding the code in the main module(project) manifest file:

add 
**`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`** in your manifest tag

add 
**`tools:replace="android:icon,android:label,android:theme"`** in your application tag

These will let Android Studio know that the icon, label and theme to be used are from that manifest and not from other projects included.

Comment: please tell me one thing tools:replace should i add this inside application tag of my project manifest or inside application tag of my library please tell me it will be really helpful for me ??